# Pre-load images and get progress

Tags: javascript

I have got the following script I use to pre-load images:

```js
export default function PreloadImages(images) {
    function loadImage(src) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                resolve(img);
            };
            img.onerror = img.onabort = function() {
                reject(src);
            };
            img.src = src;
        });
    }
    return Promise.all(images.map(src => loadImage(src)));
}
```

I then use this within a Vue component like follows:

```js
PreloadImages(this.images).then(() => (this.imagesPreloaded = true));
```

I want to be able to get progress from this however within my component so I can display for example `2/50 Images Loaded`. How would I go about doing this?

## Edit

This is what I ended up with:
`PreloadImages.js`

```js
export default function PreloadImages(images) {
    function loadImage(src) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                resolve(img);
            };
            img.onerror = img.onabort = function() {
                reject(src);
            };
            img.src = src;
        });
    }
    return images.map(src => loadImage(src));
}
```

Within my component:

```js
handlePreload() {
    PreloadImages(this.images).forEach(p => p.then(() => {
        this.imagesPreloaded++;
    }));
},
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, did the very first version of what has been accepted back then did ever really work for you?

Comment: I used parts of it, it wasn't displayed the best tbf. Will update my question with what I used.

Comment: very well ... it's good to see that an after all easy approach does not implement render logic into `PreloadImages` but does change the return value from a single promise (the former `Promise.all`) to just a list of (image preloading) promises that then separately will/can be processed according to the needs of whatever render logic/functionality.

Comment: ... having said this, it is pretty much what @izik came up with in the first place.

Comment: @PeterSeliger it was the first answer that I could use at the time and I didn't have time to go through them all sorry.

Comment: No need to be comforted. One does not only write for the OP. It's mostly for one's own joy and curiosity and for other developers that might learn from a problem and the different ways of approaching and solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should approach it, don't introduce any extra looping:

```js
var imageSrcList = [
    "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/565/565860.svg",
    "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/565/565861.svg",
    "https://Error.Done.One.Purpose",
    "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/565/565855.svg",
];

var imageContainer = document.getElementById("loadedImages");
var loadedCount = 0;

function displayCurrentLoadStatus(){
  console.log("Current load progress: ", loadedCount, " of ", imageSrcList.length);
}

function PreloadImages(images) {
    function loadImage(src) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = src;
            img.onload = function() 
            {
                ++loadedCount;
                imageContainer.appendChild(img);
                displayCurrentLoadStatus();
                resolve(img);
            };
            img.onerror = img.onabort = function() {
                reject(src);
            };
        });
    }
    // Note that I removed Promise.all, let's just return a list of promises for the images passed
    return images.map((imgSrc, i)=> loadImage(imgSrc).catch((rejectedSrcError=> rejectedSrcError)));
}

// now let's create all promises for each image in images
Promise.all(PreloadImages(imageSrcList)).then( resolvedSrcList =>
{
    // Use your resolved Src's here
    console.log("Load complete: ",loadedCount, "/",resolvedSrcList.length, " images were loaded successfully.");
});
```

```css
img{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="loadedImages"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
function PreloadImages(images) {
    let promises = [];
    images.map(src => loadImage(src));
    function loadImage(src) {
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                resolve(img);
            };
            img.onerror = img.onabort = function() {
                reject(src);
            };
            img.src = src;
        }));
    }
    Promise.all(promises);
    return promises;
}
let images = [];
let counter = 0;
let promises = PreloadImages(images);
promises.forEach(p => p.then(() => {
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

***... tldr ...***

There will be 2 different basic ideas and 4 solutions for demonstration purpose.

The first two approaches are valid in case one can not or is not allowed to change the return value (a single promise) of `PreloadImages` as from the OP's originally provided example code.

The 3rd example presents the preferred approach which is to change the return value of `PreloadImages` to a list of (image preloading) promises, whereas the 4th example is just No.3 that in addition features a real live demo of progress-bar and statistics rendering.

#### 1) Proxy based

One could use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object that one, in addition to the image source list, does provides to the `preloadImages` function.

One would use such an object in its [*set and validate*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#Validation) configuration.

Choosing a `Proxy` based approach comes with following advantages ...

1. Introducing `eventProxy` into `preloadImages` makes this new implementation agnostic to later user cases.
2. One just needs to implement functionality for an *API* that provides all necessary information about image loading states in a/the most generic way.
3. The user specific, but in the `preloadImages`' scope unknown use case, that later needs to be handled, will be provided as part of the `eventProxy`.

```js
/*export default */function preloadImages(imageSourceList, eventProxy) {

  // - the introduction of an `eventProxy` makes this implementation
  //   agnostic to later user cases.
  // - one just needs to implement the necessary api that provides
  //   information about image loading states.
  // - the user specific, but in this scope unknown use case, that later
  //   needs to be handled, will be provided as part of the `eventProxy`.

  const maxCount = imageSourceList.length;
  let successCount = 0;
  let failureCount = 0;

  function loadImage(src) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const image = new Image();

      image.onload = function() {

        resolve(image);
        ++successCount;

        eventProxy.event = {
          image,
          maxCount,
          successCount,
          failureCount
        }
      };
      image.onerror = image.onabort = function() {

        reject(src);
        ++failureCount;

        eventProxy.event = {
          image,
          maxCount,
          successCount,
          failureCount
        }
      };

      image.src = src;
    });
  }
  return Promise.all(imageSourceList.map(src => loadImage(src)));
}


function renderImageLoadProgress(evt) {
  // the render functionality goes in here ...

  console.log('renderImageLoadProgress :: evt :', evt);  
}


function isImageLoadType(type) {
  return (
       type
    && ('image' in type)
    && ('maxCount' in type)
    && ('successCount' in type)
    && ('failureCount' in type)
  )
}

const loadEventValidator = {
  set: function(obj, key, value) {

    let isSuccess = false;
    if ((key === 'event') && isImageLoadType(value)) {

      obj[key] = value;
      isSuccess = true;

      // provide render functionality as part of
      // the proxy's correct setter environment.

      renderImageLoadProgress(value);
    }
    return isSuccess;
  }
}
const loadEventProxy = new Proxy({}, loadEventValidator);


const imageSourceList = [
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1011',            // loading will fail.
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1011/5472/3648',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1012/3973/2639',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1013/4256/2832',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1013',            // loading will fail.
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1014/6016/4000',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/6000/4000',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1016/3844/2563'
];
preloadImages(imageSourceList, loadEventProxy);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

#### 2) Event based

In case of not being able making use of proxies, one easily can switch the above approach to [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) and [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent), especially since there are polyfills available that also do work in older versions of Internet Explorer. The idea behind this solution and its advantages are the same as with the former `Proxy` based one ...

```js
/*export default */function preloadImages(imageSourceList, eventTarget) {

  // - additionally injecting/providing an `eventTarget` makes this
  //   implementation agnostic to later user cases.
  // - one just needs to dispatch all relevant information via the
  //   `details` property of a custom event.
  // - the user specific, but in this scope unknown use case, will be
  //   handled from ouside via listening to the custom event's type.
  // - there are polyfills for `EventTarget` as well as for `CustomEvent`
  //   that also do work in older versions of Internet Explorer.

  const maxCount = imageSourceList.length;
  let successCount = 0;
  let failureCount = 0;

  function loadImage(src) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const image = new Image();

      image.onload = function() {

        resolve(image);
        ++successCount;

        eventTarget.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("loadstatechange", {
          detail: {
            image,
            maxCount,
            successCount,
            failureCount
          }
        }));
      };
      image.onerror = image.onabort = function() {

        reject(src);
        ++failureCount;

        eventTarget.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("loadstatechange", {
          detail: {
            image,
            maxCount,
            successCount,
            failureCount
          }
        }));
      };

      image.src = src;
    });
  }
  return Promise.all(imageSourceList.map(src => loadImage(src)));
}


function renderImageLoadProgress(evt) {
  // the render functionality goes in here ...

  console.log('renderImageLoadProgress :: evt.detail :', evt.detail);  
}
const loadEventTarget = new EventTarget();


loadEventTarget.addEventListener('loadstatechange', renderImageLoadProgress);


const imageSourceList = [
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1011',            // loading will fail.
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1011/5472/3648',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1012/3973/2639',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1013/4256/2832',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1013',            // loading will fail.
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1014/6016/4000',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/6000/4000',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1016/3844/2563'
];
preloadImages(imageSourceList, loadEventTarget);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

**Note**

Since the 2 above given approaches did not change the return value/signature of the original implementation of `PreloadImages` they had to be implemented exactly each in their own way. But both together come with a lot of additional code, the *proxy based* approach being a little fatter than the *event based* one.

#### 3) Return Array of Promises

Anyhow, if one is/was just willing to change the return value of the former `PreloadImages` to an *array of image loading promises* one could achieve a very clean and lean implementation that might look similar to the next one ...

```js
/*export default */function getAsyncLoadingImageList(imageSourceList) {

  const totalCount = imageSourceList.length;
  let successCount = 0;
  let failureCount = 0;

  function loadImage(src) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      const image = new Image();

      image.onload = function() {
        resolve({
          image,
          counts: {
            total: totalCount,
            success: ++successCount,
            failure: failureCount
          },
          success: true,
        });
      };
      image.onerror = image.onabort = function() {
        reject({
          image,
          counts: {
            total: totalCount,
            success: successCount,
            failure: ++failureCount
          },
          success: false,
        });
      };

      image.src = src;
    });
  }
  // return list of *image loading* promises.
  return imageSourceList.map(src => loadImage(src));
}


function renderImageLoadProgress(imageLoadData) {
  // the render method.
  console.log('imageLoadData : ', imageLoadData);
}


const imageSourceList = [
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1011',            // loading will fail.
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1011/5472/3648',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1012/3973/2639',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1013/4256/2832',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1013',            // loading will fail.
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1014/6016/4000',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/6000/4000',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1016/3844/2563'
];

getAsyncLoadingImageList(imageSourceList).forEach(promise =>
  promise
    .then(renderImageLoadProgress)
    .catch(renderImageLoadProgress)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

#### 4) Bonus

In order to present a real progress bar demo, the 3rd example, that already had it all, was taken as is, but now features a full blown render method instead of just logging the image-loading progress-data ...

```js
/*export default */function getAsyncLoadingImageList(imageSourceList) {

  const totalCount = imageSourceList.length;
  let successCount = 0;
  let failureCount = 0;

  function loadImage(src) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      const image = new Image();

      image.onload = function() {
        resolve({
          image,
          counts: {
            total: totalCount,
            success: ++successCount,
            failure: failureCount
          },
          success: true,
        });
      };
      image.onerror = image.onabort = function() {
        reject({
          image,
          counts: {
            total: totalCount,
            success: successCount,
            failure: ++failureCount
          },
          success: false,
        });
      };

      image.src = src;
    });
  }
  // return list of *image loading* promises.
  return imageSourceList.map(src => loadImage(src));
}


function getImageLoadProgressRenderConfig(progressContainer) {
  const elmProgress = progressContainer.querySelector('progress');

  const countsContainer = progressContainer.querySelector('.image-counts');
  const failuresContainer = progressContainer.querySelector('.load-failures');

  const elmImageCount = countsContainer.querySelector('.count');
  const elmImageTotal = countsContainer.querySelector('.total');

  const elmFailureCount = failuresContainer.querySelector('.failure-count');
  const elmCurrentCount = failuresContainer.querySelector('.current-count');

  return {
    nodes: {
      progress: {
        display: elmProgress,
        count: elmImageCount,
        total: elmImageTotal
      },
      failure: {
        display: failuresContainer,
        failureCount: elmFailureCount,
        currentCount: elmCurrentCount
      }
    },
    classNames: {
      failure: 'failures-exist'
    }
  };
}


function renderImageLoadProgressViaBoundConfig(imageLoadData) {
  const imageCounts = imageLoadData.counts;

  const imageCountTotal = imageCounts.total;
  const imageCountSuccess = imageCounts.success;
  const imageCountFailure = imageCounts.failure;
  const imageCountCurrent = (imageCountSuccess + imageCountFailure);

  const renderConfig = this;
  const renderNodes = renderConfig.nodes;

  const progressNodes = renderNodes.progress;
  const failureNodes = renderNodes.failure;

  const classNameFailure = renderConfig.classNames.failure;
  const isFailureOnDisplay =
    failureNodes.display.classList.contains(classNameFailure);

  progressNodes.display.textContent = `${ imageCountCurrent } \/ ${ imageCountTotal }`;
  progressNodes.display.value = imageCountCurrent;
  progressNodes.count.textContent = imageCountCurrent;

  if (!imageLoadData.success) {
    if (!isFailureOnDisplay) {

      failureNodes.display.classList.add(classNameFailure);
    }
    failureNodes.failureCount.textContent = imageCountFailure;

  } else if (isFailureOnDisplay) {

    failureNodes.currentCount.textContent = imageCountCurrent
  }
}

function preloadImagesAndRenderLoadProgress(imageSourceList, progressContainer) {
  const totalImageCount = imageSourceList.length;

  const renderConfig = getImageLoadProgressRenderConfig(progressContainer);
  const renderNodes = renderConfig.nodes;

  const progressNodes = renderNodes.progress;
  const failureNodes = renderNodes.failure;

  const renderImageLoadProgress =
    renderImageLoadProgressViaBoundConfig.bind(renderConfig);

  failureNodes.display.classList.remove(renderConfig.classNames.failure);

  failureNodes.failureCount.textContent = 0;
  failureNodes.currentCount.textContent = 0;

  progressNodes.display.max = totalImageCount;
  progressNodes.total.textContent = totalImageCount;

  renderImageLoadProgress({
    counts: {
      success: 0,
      failure: 0
    },
    success: true,
  });

  getAsyncLoadingImageList(imageSourceList).forEach(promise => promise
    .then(renderImageLoadProgress)
    .catch(renderImageLoadProgress)
  );
}


const imageSourceListWithFailure = [
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1011',            // loading will fail.
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1011/5472/3648',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1012/3973/2639',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1013/4256/2832',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1013',            // loading will fail.
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1014/6016/4000',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/6000/4000',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1016/3844/2563',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1018',            // loading will fail.
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1018/3914/2935',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1019/5472/3648',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1020/4288/2848',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1021',            // loading will fail.
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1021/2048/1206',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1022/6000/3376',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1023/3955/2094'
];
const imageSourceListWithoutFailure = [
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1039/6945/4635',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1038/3914/5863',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1037/5760/3840',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1036/4608/3072',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1035/5854/3903',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1033/2048/1365',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1032/2880/1800',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1031/5446/3063',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1029/4887/2759',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1028/5184/3456',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1027/2848/4272',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/1026/4621/3070'
];

preloadImagesAndRenderLoadProgress(
  imageSourceListWithFailure,
  document.querySelector('#loading-with-failure')
);
preloadImagesAndRenderLoadProgress(
  imageSourceListWithoutFailure,
  document.querySelector('#loading-without-failure')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }

.image-loading-progress {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.image-loading-progress,
.image-loading-progress > span,
.image-loading-progress progress {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.image-loading-progress > .load-failures {
  display: none
}
.image-loading-progress > .load-failures.failures-exist {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<label class="image-loading-progress" id="loading-with-failure">
  <progress value="0" max="0">0 / 0</progress>
  <span class="image-counts">
    ...
    <span class="count">0</span>
    out of
    <span class="total">0</span>
    images finished loading ...
  </span>
  <span class="load-failures">
    ...
    <span class="failure-count">0</span>
    out of
    <span class="current-count">0</span>
    images are not available ...
  </span>
</label>

<label class="image-loading-progress" id="loading-without-failure">
  <progress value="0" max="0">0 / 0</progress>
  <span class="image-counts">
    ...
    <span class="count">0</span>
    out of
    <span class="total">0</span>
    images finished loading ...
  </span>
  <span class="load-failures">
    ...
    <span class="failure-count">0</span>
    out of
    <span class="current-count">0</span>
    images are not available ...
  </span>
</label>
```